# application is now running on server or client

Tags: vb.net

I use VB.NET for a Windows application.

How can I find out if the application is now running on a server or client (programmatically)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to see if there are multiple instances on the same machine, or on your network?

Comment: I want to know if the application files are local , and my application is running on the server system or my files are on another system in network. and I just run the application..

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to find out before you will get any sensible answers.

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense unless you are talking about a file share or a mapped drive.  It doesn't run "on the server" in that case, it is just where the EXE was retrieved from.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to know if the exe is shortcut(or running throw a mapnetwork drive) . or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little ambiguous since any machine can be a server or a client.  One way you could check is by inspecting the  `Environment.MachineName` variable:

```
If  Environment.MachineName = "MyServerName" Then
  ''Do something here.
End If
```

MSDN :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx